# Are Java Hibernate Criteria leftOuterJoin criterion useless?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have a simple Criteria like this:

Student has only one School (this is just a illustrative example).

```
private List<Student>getData()
{
    final Session session = ...............
    final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
    final Criteria criteria2 = criteria.createCriteria("school","school",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,isNotNull("status"));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

I need the Students even if they not have a School... but if they have the School I need the `Status` is not `NULL`.

I was wondering if this

```
 criteria.createCriteria("school","school",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,isNotNull("status"));
```

Filterings using `left-outer-join` are useless because I am getting the `Schools with null status`

But if I apply this

```
final Criteria criteria2 = criteria.createCriteria("school","school",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria2.add(isNotNull("status"));
```

It works or if I apply:

```
criteria.createCriteria("school","school",JoinType.INNER_JOIN,isNotNull("status"));
```

works as well.

Should I never put criteria or filters in `createCriteria o createAlias` using left-Outer-Join are they just ignored or how can that be used?

What are the diffs between using in the `ON` or use the same criteria in regular criteria using `.add(`?

Comment: Are you sure your first code snippet is correct? You creating 2 criterias, but you get list using first one. You need to use createAlias (which is actually a JOIN) instead of createCriteria

Comment: createCriteria or createAlias is the same in this case. and yes is correct.

Comment: i use createCriteria because i create another JOIN later with the 2 one.